# Reversing a file with Stack ADT

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

I have a Stack ADT which when called to create (stack.create()) returns a tuple of form ("This Stack contains", list()). Other things in ADT include push/pop/size/is_empty

Now I have a file, file.txt, that is like so

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

and I want it to output like

```
8 7 6 5
4 3 2 1
```

My code so far is something like this:

```
import StackADT as stack
file = open("file.txt", "r")

stack_main = stack.create()
stack_rev = stack.create()

for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    stack.push(stack_main, line)

print(stack_main)
```

`print(stack_main)` outputs

```
("This Stack Contains", [['1','2','3','4'],['5','6','7','8']])
```

then I push the `['5','6','7','8']` list onto my second stack like so:

```
stack.push(stack_rev, stack.pop(stack_main))
print(stack_rev)
```

which gives:

```
("This Stack Contains", [['5', '6', '7', '8']])
```

Now my question is how do I pop the items `5,6,7,8` from stack_rev?

I tried to use a for loop but it gave me an error. I also tried adding an if statement like so:

```
for i in stack_rev:
    if i == 'This Stack Contains':
        pass
    else:
        for x in i:
            print(stack.pop(stack_rev))
```

but it just returns an empty stack like so: ("This Stack Contains", [])
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nice try but there are a couple of problems with your code.

1. You are calling `stack.push` with a `list` as the second argument where, if I have understood you correctly, you should be pushing an element.
2. You are pushing into `stack_rev` only once. You must use a loop so that each element from `stack_main` gets pushed into `stack_rev`.

### Solution

This is how you should be building `stack_main`:

```
for line in file:
    for element in line.split():
        stack.push(stack_main, element)
```

This is how you should be reversing your stack:

```
for _ in range(len(stack_main[1])):  # loop n times; where n = length of stack
    stack.push(stack_rev, stack.pop(stack_main))
```

### Printing your stack

If you print `stack_rev` by popping elements off it, you will again be reversing the elements (which will cancel the first reversing). I recommend you loop over the `list` in your `stack` to print the elements.

Like this:

```
for elem in stack_rev[1]:
    print(elem, end=" ")
```

### None of my concerns, but

You are doing OOP wrong! The implementation of StackADT you are showing here is very C-like. Instead of having a module with functions accepting the target stack, create a Stack class and implement methods.

You might have not understood what I said above if you are a beginner, but do research a bit about OOP (object-oriented programming).